# Button click with CommandName is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have placed a textbox and a button with CommandName method. there i want to place a Required field validator, it is working fine when textbox is empty but button click is not firing.

Here's the aspx code:

```
<td class="topRight">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" MaxLength="500" CssClass="gvtxt" 
        Height="60px" TextMode="MultiLine" style="vertical-align:middle"
        Width="300px" ToolTip="Enter Comments"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rftxtComments" ControlToValidate="txtComments" 
        ErrorMessage="Enter Comment" ValidationGroup="rfComment" runat="server" /> 
</td>
<td class="topLeft">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnRem" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/btn_save.gif"
        ValidationGroup="rfComment" CommandName="abc"></asp:ImageButton>
</td>
```

please help

Comment: is the button placed in some data binding control i.e. grid, repeater etc